# FreeSwitch - I can't hear sound on Amazon EC2 server

Tags: amazon-ec2, freeswitch

I've successfully installed FreeSwitch on Local Linux Server (CentOS 6.5), and it worked fine. I could make a call and hear sound from other device.

I followed exactly same process on Amazon EC2 CentOS server. http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Linux_Quick_Install_Guide

I opened all firewalls in case http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Firewall

I can see that server is running fine. However, I couldn't hear any sound on EC2 Server. Does anyone had this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed this guideline and it worked well.
http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Amazon_EC2

Answer (score 2):

did you try to catch the packet trace with tcpdump?
How does EC2 network look like? Do you get a private IP address or a public one?

Comment: I followed this guideline and it worked well. http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Amazon_EC2