# FreeSwitch - I can't hear sound on Amazon EC2 server too

Tags: amazon-ec2, freeswitch

I followed the steps given [here](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Amazon_EC2) but I am getting the following errors:

```
# ec2-authorize default -P udp -p 5060 -O, --aws-access-key AWS_ACCESS_KEY
Required option '-W, --aws-secret-key KEY' missing (-h for usage)
```

```
# ec2-authorize default -P udp -p 5060 -O, --aws-access-key AWS_ACCESS_KEY  -W, --aws-secret-key AWS_SECRET_KEY
Client.AuthFailure: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 401; Error Code: AuthFailure; Request ID: 005cab49-0620-4740-971c-39804c55750f)
```

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348194/freeswitch-i-cant-hear-sound-on-amazon-ec2-server) has no answers too.

Comment: I guess this should explain everything: https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Amazon+EC2

Answer (score 1):

Use -W OR --aws-secret-key option, not both of them. Like this:

ec2-authorize default -P udp -p 5060 -O AWS_ACCESS_KEY -W AWS_SECRET_KEY

(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress.html)

or you can just open the ports via EC2 Web GUI.

Don't forget about ports for RTP (UDP protocol 16384-32768), or you will not hear the sound.

Comment: Thank you. I do like that replace AWS_ACCESS_KEY & AWS_SECRET_KEY with the ture strings. after finished.I start freeswitch,but still no voice.